# Understanding python list calls

Tags: python

Please can someone explain how the answer is 5? Sorry if this seems like a simple question but just trying to understand how to get to the answer.

```
a = [1,2,[3,4],6,5]
print(a[a[2][1]])
```

Comment: Can be shortened to `a[4]`, because `a[2][1]` is `4`. `a[4]` is then `5`.

Comment: I may have worked it out ...it’s the 2nd number from list 1 added to the 1st number in list 2...I think

Comment: print all the interim values to figure it out

Comment: I now understand the answer and how to get there. Thanks for all your input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a[2] = [3,4]
a[2][1] = 4 # second element of the list a[2]
a[a[2][1]] = a[4] = 5
```

Remember that in Python index starts from 0.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> a = [1,2,[3,4],6,5]
>>> print(a[a[2][1]])
5
```

The reason is,

```
>>> a[2]
[3, 4]
>>> a[2][1]
4
```

So you are actually trying to get a[4], which is

```
>>> a[4]
5
>>> print(a[a[2][1]])
5
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to decompose what is going on:

`a[2]` is `[3,4]`
`a[2][1]` is `4`
So `a[a[2][1]]` is `5` (4th element of `a`, starting at index `0`).

Answer (score 0):

Lets work inside out -

```
print(a[2]) 
>> [3,4]
```

That means `a[2][1]` is -

```
print(a[2][1])
>> 4
```

Hence `a[4]` is -

```
print(a[4])
>>5
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's do it on a few lines instead of one.
Starting from the most inner which will be evaluated first.

```
x = a[2] # 3,4
y = x[1] # 4
a[y] # is a[4] which is the fifth element of a which is 5
```